# Reusing ObjectInputStream throws StreamCorruptedException

Tags: java, sockets, networking, inputstream, outputstream

I have a client-server application. Where the client sends an object and the server sends the same object back, a simple echo server. The code below works fine if I am making a new instance of `Client` for every new request. However, if I use an existing instance of the client, it gives me a `java.io.StreamCorruptedException` and `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

Client

```
Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, port);


in = new ObjectInputStream(
            new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

//calling this each time I have a new request
out.writeObject(request);
out.flush();
Object object = in.readObject();
```

Server

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
new Thread(new ClientWorker(clientSocket)).start();
```

ClientWorker

```
public void run() {
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream out =
                    new        ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            Object inputObject;

      while(true) {
            while ((inputObject = in.readObject()) != null) {
                  out.writeObject(inputObject);
            }

            out.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

when the following code is executed in the reused Client

`in.readObject()`;

I get the exception

> java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1497)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1748)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)

Comment: Object streams are tricky. You can't just reuse them like that due to all sorts of header information that is sent besides the objects themselves.

Comment: Did out checkout the java docs for the respective classes and when this exception is thrown? Can you point out the lines where these exceptions occur.

Comment: @bot I have pointed them out

Comment: @Kayaman so what I need to do?

Comment: @user592748 I would advise you not to use `ObjectStreams` at all in network communication, and use normal byte streams instead.

Comment: @user592748 Have you tried out flushing out the outputstream everytime after writing object. That is:while(true) {
            while ((inputObject = in.readObject()) != null) {
                  out.writeObject(inputObject);   out.flush();
           }
        }

Comment: it was apparently a problem with synchronization

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was solved after I synchronized over the input and output object streams.

```
synchronized(this) {
    while ((inputObject = in.readObject()) != null) {
        out.writeObject(inputObject);
    }
}
```

And

```
synchronized(this) {
   out.writeObject(request);
   out.flush();
   Object object = in.readObject();
}
```

Comment: `while ((inputObject = in.readObject()) != null)` is not a valid way to read an object input stream. `readObject()` only returns `null` when you *wrote* a `null`. When you reach end of stream it throws `EOFException`, and you need to catch it and break when it happens.